# Cryptography python installation error with rust -- Air-gapped installation

Tags: python-3.x, rust, rust-crates

I'm trying to install ansible core in an airgap environment, the problem is that when I install cryptography 40.0.1 it requires rust installed.

I install rust using yum ( we have a private repository, that is why I can install rust in an air gapped environment ), but when I try to install cryptography it throws this error:

```
running build_ext
running build_rust
cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module pyo3/abi3-py36 -- --crate-type cdylib
    Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: github.com); class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: github.com); class=Net (12)
error: Unable to update registry `crates-io`

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: github.com); class=Net (12)

    =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
    If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
    successfully install cryptography:
    1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
       users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
    2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ for specific
       instructions for your platform.
    3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
       https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/
    4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
       https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust

    Python: 3.9.13
    platform: Linux-4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.28
    pip: 20.2.4
    setuptools: 67.6.1
    setuptools_rust: 1.5.2
    rustc: 1.62.1 (Red Hat 1.62.1-1.module+el8.7.0+16002+ac58477b)
    =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features 'pyo3/extension-module pyo3/abi3-py36' -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101
```

Is there a way to install the missing crates in an air gapped environment?

Comment: [`cargo vendor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-vendor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about your environment, nor how yum works.

But it seems like your problem happens because cargo tries to update the index to do its job.

Somewhere between `yum install x` and `networking error` this command is triggered:

```bash
cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module pyo3/abi3-py36 -- --crate-type cdylib
```

But for you not to get that error you need pass a `--offline` flag, something like this:

```bash
cargo rustc --offline --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module pyo3/abi3-py36 -- --crate-type cdylib
```

I guess the answer is in how to pass that specific argument to cargo in your environment when you make `yum install`