# Django: how to generate random number inside a slug field

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `Product`, when the user create an objects inside a `Product` model, I want to generate some random number inside a `Product` model field `Slug` like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010275/cryptography-python-installation-error-with-rush-airgapped-installation
```

Take a look at this Stack Overflow question, you may see the domain name at first, and some path name called `questions`, and some random number at the end of the `questions`, I think it should look like this in django `path`:

```
path('question/random_number/<slug:slug>/', views.some_views_name, name='Redirect-name')
```

All the examples i found in the internet does not do something like this, so how can i do this in django?

model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product-image')
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=11)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def get_user_public_url(self):
        return reverse('Public-Profile', kwargs={'slug': self.user.profile.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Comment: That is not a random number, that is the primary key. Indeed, the previous one also works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010330/extraction-of-a-table-from-summary-function

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  But it not working when two objects has the same `name`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you can only get number when you are using `pk` as a `slug` like this in the path: `path('question/<int:pk>/', views.someViews, name='Page-Redirect')`, but mine was this: `path('product/<slug:slug>/', views.product_infor, name='View-Product')`

Comment: no, you can use any number. Often the primary key is used, especially since an index on primary keys is often smaller and (partly therefore) faster.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow does not use a "random number". It simply uses the primary key. Indeed, you can browse to a post where the number is a decrement (or increment) of that number, and that will (often) show a post as well.

You thus can define a view with:

```
path(
    'question/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', views.some_views_name, name='Redirect-name'
)
```

In your model you can pass the primary key:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …

    def get_user_public_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'Public-Profile',
            kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug': self.user.profile.slug},
        )
```

Class-based views, like a `DetailView` will automatically filter on a primary key, if it can find one. For a function-based view, you can work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def some_view_name(request, pk, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk, slug=slug)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`django-autoslug`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).